# Stuck when migrating Metabase from H2 DB to mysql

Tags: java, mysql, h2, metabase

I am using metabase version v0.41.2 with H2 DB and running it on Windows server.
Now I want to migrate from H2 db to mysql. Following is the command used

```
java -jar metabase.jar load-from-h2 /path/to/metabase.db
```

After executing the command, it is stuck at point `Migration lock is cleared. Running migrations...` and it does not go ahead. Following is the log generated

```
[main] TRACEmetabase.util.i18n - Translated "Successfully verified {0} {1} application database connection." for site locale #locale "en" -> "Successfully verified H2 1.4.197 (2018-03-18) application database connection."   
[main] INFO metabase.db.setup - Successfully verified H2 1.4.197 (2018-03-18) application database connection.    
[main] TRACEmetabase.util.i18n - Translated "Running Database Migrations..." for site locale #locale "en" -> "Running Database Migrations..."   
[main] INFO metabase.db.setup - Running Database Migrations...   
[main] TRACEmetabase.util.i18n - Translated "Set transaction to automatically roll back..." for site locale #locale "en" -> "Set transaction to automatically roll back..."   
[main] DEBUGmetabase.db.setup - Set transaction to automatically roll back...   
[main] TRACEmetabase.util.i18n - Translated "Disable auto-commit..." for site locale #locale "en" -> "Disable auto-commit..."   
[main] DEBUGmetabase.db.setup - Disable auto-commit...   
[main] TRACEmetabase.util.i18n - Translated "Setting up Liquibase..." for site locale #locale "en" -> "Setting up Liquibase..."   
[main] INFO metabase.db.setup - Setting up Liquibase...   
[main] TRACEmetabase.util.i18n - Translated "Liquibase is ready." for site locale #locale "en" -> "Liquibase is ready."   
[main] INFO metabase.db.setup - Liquibase is ready.   
[main] TRACEmetabase.util.i18n - Translated "Checking if Database has unrun migrations..." for site locale #locale "en" -> "Checking if Database has unrun migrations..."   
[main] INFO metabase.db.liquibase - Checking if Database has unrun migrations...   
[main] TRACEmetabase.util.i18n - Translated "Database has unrun migrations. Waiting for migration lock to be cleared..." for site locale #locale "en" -> "Database has unrun migrations. Waiting for migration lock to be cleared..."   
[main] INFO metabase.db.liquibase - Database has unrun migrations. Waiting for migration lock to be cleared...   
[main] TRACEmetabase.util.i18n - Translated "Migration lock is cleared. Running migrations..." for site locale #locale "en" -> "Migration lock is cleared. Running migrations..."   
[main] INFO metabase.db.liquibase - Migration lock is cleared. Running migrations...
```

Comment: Have you managed to perform this migration successfully? I am getting stuck with another error